# Change attribute title at tag span including php from ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax, zend-framework2

I am using Zend Framework 2, I want to translate a string on my index.html which shows me a tool tip when I hover on a span tag. The problem is that this value has to change because I make an action with ajax and I want to show another type of message. Look my success' ajax code:

```
success: function (data, status) {
                $(this).switchEyeSpan(thisRow);
                var status = "success";
                var id = thisRow.attr('data');
                $(this).messageEntity(status, id, data.message);
                var translate = "<?php echo $this->translate('tooltip_eye_pub'); ?>";
                if(ischecked) {
                    translate = "<?php echo $this->translate('tooltip_eye_hide'); ?>";
                }
                $('.tooltip-'+id).attr('title', translate);
            },
```

As you can see what I want is to change the title from a tag depending on the variable ischecked.

This is my index.html file :

```
<span data="<?php echo $center->id ?>"  class="tooltip-<?php echo $center->id; ?> checkbox-published-span glyphicon <?php echo ($center->published == 0) ? 'glyphicon-eye-open' : 'glyphicon-eye-close'; ?>">
                    </span>
```

The result of this code is getting the php code from java script as a string. How can I change this string to php code?

Comment: I am not sure you realise that PHP runs purely on the server and JS on the client... If you see the rendered page (view-source) all the texts you need must be in the page if you do not ajax them in

Comment: what is the value of ischecked variable and where u initialized it?

Answer (score 1):

move these rows outside ajax and try if it is working or not?

```
var translate = "<?php echo $this->translate('tooltip_eye_pub'); ?>";
if(ischecked) {
    translate = "<?php echo $this->translate('tooltip_eye_hide'); ?>";
}
```